# Questions relating to install ofbiz on Red Hat's OpenShift PaaS

Tags: openshift, ofbiz

Best to all ,

I wonder if it is possible to run ofbiz in OpenShift . I tried to do an installation and to start I have the following error:

```
#. / Ant start
Buildfile : / var/lib/openshift/528501ba4382ec7016000175/app-deployments/apache-ofbiz-12.04.02/build.xml
start:
     [ java ] Start.java configuration file using org / ofbiz / base / start / start.properties
     [ java ] September OFBIZ_HOME to - / var/lib/openshift/528501ba4382ec7016000175/app-deployments/apache-ofbiz-12.04.02
     [ java ] Exception in thread "main" org.ofbiz.base.start.StartupException : Could not create server socket ( / 127.0.0.1:10523 )
     [ java ] at $ org.ofbiz.base.start.Start AdminPortThread . <init> ( Start.java : 405 )
     [ java ] at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.createListenerThread ( Start.java : 163)
     [ java ] at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.init ( Start.java : 222)
     [ java ] at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.main ( Start.java : 131)
     [ java ] Caused by: java.net.BindException : Permission denied
     [ java ] at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind ( Native Method)
     [ java ] at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind ( AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java : 376 )
     [ java ] at java.net.ServerSocket.bind ( ServerSocket.java : 376 )
     [ java ] at java.net.ServerSocket . <init> ( ServerSocket.java : 237 )
     [ java ] at $ org.ofbiz.base.start.Start AdminPortThread . <init> ( Start.java : 403 )
     [ java ] ... 3 more
     [ java ] Java Result : 1
```

Is it possible to somehow configure the ports to have permission to start ofbiz ?

Thank you very much to all

Answer (score 0):

You must to configure the ports to use before to compile in "framework/start/src/org/ofbiz/base/start/start.properties" and "framework/start/src/org/ofbiz/base/start/jetty.properties".

Goog luck!